# The multi-part identifier "publicdb.dbo.TBL_ITEM.FLD_PID" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server-2008

I try to insert data from 1 table to other table (all difference database)
I got some error like this "The multi-part identifier "publicdb.dbo.TBL_ITEM.FLD_PID" could not be bound."

I use this command in SQL2005 it work fine. but in 2008 fail
anyone can help me?

this is my code.

```
INSERT INTO [publicdb].[dbo].[TBL_ITEM]
       ([FLD_PID]
       ,[FLD_QUESTITEM]
       ,[FLD_NAME]
       ,[FLD_NJ]
       ,[FLD_RESIDE1]
       ,[FLD_RESIDE2]
       ,[FLD_SEX]
       ,[FLD_DF]
       ,[FLD_AT1]
       ,[FLD_AT2]
       ,[FLD_LEVEL]
       ,[FLD_JOB_LEVEL]
       ,[FLD_ZX]
       ,[FLD_EL]
       ,[FLD_WX]
       ,[FLD_WXJD]
       ,[FLD_MONEY]
       ,[FLD_WEIGHT]
       ,[FLD_TYPE]
       ,[FLD_MAGIC1]
       ,[FLD_MAGIC2]
       ,[FLD_MAGIC3]
       ,[FLD_MAGIC4]
       ,[FLD_MAGIC5]
       ,[FLD_DES]
       ,[FLD_SIDE])
 SELECT
       [FLD_PID]
       ,[FLD_QUESTITEM]
       ,[FLD_NAME]
       ,[FLD_NJ]
       ,[FLD_RESIDE1]
       ,[FLD_RESIDE2]
       ,[FLD_SEX]
       ,[FLD_DF]
       ,[FLD_AT1]
       ,[FLD_AT2]
       ,[FLD_LEVEL]
       ,[FLD_JOB_LEVEL]
       ,[FLD_ZX]
       ,[FLD_EL]
       ,[FLD_WX]
       ,[FLD_WXJD]
       ,[FLD_MONEY]
       ,[FLD_WEIGHT]
       ,[FLD_TYPE]
       ,[FLD_MAGIC1]
       ,[FLD_MAGIC2]
       ,[FLD_MAGIC3]
       ,[FLD_MAGIC4]
       ,[FLD_MAGIC5]
       ,[FLD_DES]
       ,[FLD_SIDE]
       FROM [Z_publicdb].[dbo].[TBL_XWWL_ITEM]
       where [Z_publicdb].[dbo].[TBL_XWWL_ITEM].[FLD_PID] <> [publicdb].[dbo].[TBL_ITEM].[FLD_PID]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use something like [publicdb].[dbo].[TBL_ITEM].[FLD_PID] in where clause for field comparison.
Put appropriate join condition of table [Z_publicdb].[dbo].[TBL_XWWL_ITEM] with [publicdb].[dbo].[TBL_ITEM] and you will get proper insertion.